# Android Studio Fragment Passing Context To Custom Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, kotlin, fragment, custom-adapter

How can I make fragment with custom gridview?
I've tried with activity and it passed context from activity, but I don't know how to do it with Fragment. I've tried with "activity" but still I get null result from adapter.

My Fragment:

```
   val example = listOf<String>(
        "Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3", "Product 4", "Product 5", "Product 6", "Product 7", "Product 8"
    )
    val adapter = GridviewAdapter(this, example )
    grid_view.adapter = adapter
```

My adapter:

```
    class GridviewAdapter(private val context: Context, private val list_produk: List<String>) : BaseAdapter() {
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

    val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_gridview_produk, parent, false)

    val nama = view.findViewById<AppCompatTextView>(R.id.txt_nama)
    nama.text = list_produk.get(position)

    val harga = view.findViewById<AppCompatTextView>(R.id.txt_harga)
    harga.text = "Rp 65.000".toString()

    return view
}
```

Error:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.latihan.myapplication/com.latihan.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: grid_viewmust not be null
```

My XML

```
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <FrameLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".HomeFragment" 
         android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
         <GridView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:numColumns="2" 
                android:id="@+id/grid_view"/>
     </FrameLayout>`
```

Comment: Can you add to the question where you define the grid_view (in xml) and how you are using it in fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize you gridview by findViewById()?
and to pass context from a fragment use getContext()....

```
val adapter = GridviewAdapter(getContext(), example )
```

Comment: No, I just call it's id since it can be done with kotlin. and yes in java I could use getContext() but I don't know how to do it with kotlin

Comment: You can check this link [link](https://medium.com/@shafran/fragment-getcontext-vs-requirecontext-ffc9157d6bbe)

Comment: Thanks, but still gives me "grid_view must not be null" error message

Answer (score -1):

[**[![`[

> [enter link description here](http://192.168.88.49)

][1](http://192.168.88.49)`][1](http://192.168.88.49)][1](http://192.168.88.49)**][1](http://192.168.88.49)

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer for the question.